# Supress Warnings from Windows Event Logs with Source MySQL

Tags: mysql, windows

Is there a way to suppress the warnings arising from MySQL on Windows Event Logs?
I tried suppressing the warnings from mysql error log - it worked but it's continuing to write to event logs.

My version of MySQL : 5.6.24

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like after trying out on mysql 5.6, either you can turn off the events completely or switch them on but you can't suppress only warnings/errors/information/verbose..

But, from what I wanted to achieve it's possible in mysql 5.7 with log_error_verbosity=1

Ref: : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-log.html